# CSS is loading to the page, but not showing up fully

Tags: html, css

[image]
padding-top is working correctly, but background-color is crossed out
how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

A crossed-out property in Chrome refers to that property being overridden. And this is definitely the case here. Your **reboot.scss** is overriding the background color in your **style.css**. This is where you have overridden your `background-color` property:

[image]

Either remove that line or change the second line from

```
background-color: yellow;
```

to

```
background-color: yellow !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most times this happens because there is already another style with higher precedence taking place. in other words, there is already a background-color style overriding your style.

Answer (score 1):

reboot.scss is overriding backgroud-color from style.css
If you post your code may be I can help you more. Thanks.